# how to run .Gif images in background during sleep in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am working on vb.net window form application. Here i have a main window where there several .gif images. These images will animate according to values coming from database. On clicking any images a popup window will open. On this Popup window there are six button. On clicking any of the button the respective value in Sql server database Table will updated to 1 and after 1 second the same value will get updated to 0. For this i used following code

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Try
        If (Label1.Text.Contains("Drag")) Then
            tag2 = "D" + Label1.Text.Substring((Len(Label1.Text.ToString()) - 1), 1)
        Else
            tag2 = Label1.Text.Trim().ToString()
        End If
        ObjTags.Name = tag2 + ".Start"

        btnStart.Enabled = False

        ObjTags.DigitalValue = 1
        i = ObjTags.UpdateConValue(6)
        Application.DoEvents()
        Thread.Sleep(1000)


        ObjTags.DigitalValue = 0
        i = ObjTags.UpdateConValue(6)

        btnStart.Enabled = True

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

This is working good. On clicking button the respective value in database gets updated to 1 and after 1 second it will gets updated to 0. But during this operation the .gif images in main page stop animating. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in UI thread, you are commanding the UI thread to sleep, so UI will not update during that time. Also when trying to update database in UI thread, the UI thread will be busy and no update in the UI will be done during that time.

**Async/Await**

You may want to use a thread or switch to async/await for updating database and also applying the delay:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await UpdateDatabase()
    Await Task.Delay(1000)
    UpdateUI()
End Sub

Private Async Function UpdateDatabase() as Task
    'Do time-consuming task here
End Function

Private sub UpdateUI()
    'Update UI here
End sub
```

**Thread**

In your case since you are using .NET 4.0, you need to use thread like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ts = New Threading.ThreadStart(Sub()
                UpdateDatabase()
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                Me.Invoke(Sub()
                              UpdateUI()
                          End Sub)
             End Sub)
    Dim t = New Threading.Thread(ts)
    t.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateDatabase()
    'Do time-consuming task here
End Sub
Private sub UpdateUI()
    'Update UI here
End sub
```

Comment: when i use Await  there is showing a error as it is not declared or accessible. and also it is showing that delay is not a member of system.threading.tasks.task

Comment: When i write Async before sub it showing error that end of statement expected.

Comment: Which version of VS? Which Version of .NET?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010.

Comment: As far as I remember Async/Await have been introduced with .NET Framework 4.5 and you cannot use it in VS 2010 .